# Limit new products on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I try to limit the new products on the homepage with the following code:

```
        <block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/homepage-new-products.phtml">
            <action method="setProductsCount"><count>2</count></action>
        </block>
```

Unfortunately this does not work, the setProductsCount is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Limit number of products shown on homepage, list.phtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281060/limit-number-of-products-shown-on-homepage-list-phtml)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="4" category_id="13" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

To accomplish this using layout.xml then use `setLimit`

```
<action method="setLimit">4</action>
```

Eg

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/homepage-new-products.phtml">
    <action method="setLimit">4</action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `_getProductCollection()` method in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` you will see that the blocks collection has no way to limit the actual list of items.

It can set the page count, using `setProductsCount` 
Theoretically you can use this to limit the result, by not placing a pager as part of the block display, thus only the first page will be shown - the end effect is just a limit of the first page of products.

A while back, I did come up with a away to insert a limit (`product_count`) to catalog list filters. In my examples I use the CMS {{block}} tags, but it should also work from standard layout directives

You can read about this via my blog entry: http://www.proxiblue.com.au/blog/smarter-cms-category-product-limits/

This is also available as a module via github: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/CatalogListFilters

Comment: In 1.9.0.1 it actually reads
`->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())->setCurPage(1)` so it looks like it returns one page, of size getProductsCount(), there is a setProductsCount function, that's why OP is trying to call it like that in his question

Comment: good work .... it is help me a t today

Answer (score 0):

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>
<action method="setProductsCount"><count>2</count></action>
```

Try it like this

Comment: Tried before, does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" products_count="2" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Try this one :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can add *"column_count"* to use product limit**

{{block type="catalog/product_new" ***column_count="5"***  template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using

```
$productCollection->setPageSize(2);
```

in your block class.

Answer (score 0):

`setProductsCount` and `setColumnCount` did not do  this

`setProductsCount`  is `define current perpage collection`

and  `setColumnCount`  define  `no of column for collection`

you need to limit on collection 
using action method

```
 <action method="setLimit"></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to display recent product:-

```
<?php
                            $allproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id','desc')->setPageSize(5)->getData();
                            $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                            foreach($allproduct as $product){
                            echo '<div class="product_box">';
                            $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                            $productid = $product['entity_id'];
                            $_product = $obj->load($productid); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
                            $productName = $_product->getName();
                            $productDescription = $_product->getDescription();
                            $productImage = $_product->getImageUrl();
                            $productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
                            $productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
                            $addToCartUrl = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
                            echo '<a href="'.$productUrl.'"><img src="'.$productImage.'" alt="Shoes 1" /></a>';
                            echo '<p>"'.$productDescription.'"</p>';
                            echo '<p class="product_price">"'.$productPrice.'"</p>';
                            echo '<a href="'.$productUrl.'" class="detail"></a>';
                            echo "<div class='carousel-title'>";
                            echo $_product->getName();
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo '<a href="'.$addToCartUrl.'" class="addtocart"></a>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            }

                        ?>
```